# Deletion not working for every id using for loop in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have table of records. which contains deletion option. when on click delete it will popup one text area and then on click ok in that popup it will delete that record. It is working only for the first record. when i click on second record it is not working. I thought it is id problem. But i didn't get any idea to solve this problem.

Here is my code.

```
<%for(int i=0;i<joborderlist.size();i++){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=i+1 %></td>
            <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getSno()%></td>
            <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getJobCreatesOnasString()%></td>
            <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getCaseno()%></td>
            <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getAdjustername()%></td>
            <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getOwnername()%></td>
            <td><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px solid black;" id="delete">Cancel
                </a>
            </td>

             </tr>
        <div id="backsheet"></div>
            <div id="popupBox">
                  <span class="buttonClose">X</span> 
                  <div id="top1">
                </div><BR><BR>
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/DeleteRecords" method="post" id="wlogForm" autocomplete="off">
                    <!-- hidden values -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="joborder_id" value="<%=joborderlist.get(i).getSno()%>" id="branchid">
                    <input type="hidden" name="deleted_by" value="<%=session.getAttribute("emp_email")%>" id="branchid">
                    <span class="title_txt"><span id="add_ttl">Reason :</span></span>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="reason" id="reason" style="margin: -34px 7px -30px 6px;"></textarea><br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                   <div><span id="reasonmsg" style="color: red;margin-right: 190px;"></span></div>
                  <div class="submit"><input id="branchbutton" type="submit" value="Ok" name="submit" onclick="return validation();" style="margin-left: 115px;"/>
                                      <input id="branchbutton" type="button" value="Cancel" name="submit" class="buttonCancel" style="margin: 17px 0px 0px 19px;"/>
                  </div>
                 </form>
               </div>
             <%}%>
```

This is my script for popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#delete").click(function() {
                    $('#branchbutton').show();
                    $("#popupBox").show();
                    $("#backsheet").show();
                        $(".buttonClose").click(function() {
                            $("#popupBox").hide();
                            $("#backsheet").hide();
                         });
                   $(".buttonCancel").click(function() {
                        $("#popupBox").hide();
                        $("#backsheet").hide();
                       });
                   });
                });
         </script>
```

This is my records table

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: id should be unique .. change id="delete" to class="delete"  and use it like  $('.delete') .. don't duplicate IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly close your first click event,use `$(this).closest('.form-horizontal')` to get the relative elements:

add a class to the link

```
<td><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px solid black;" class="cancel">Cancel
                </a>
            </td>
```

js:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function() {
                 $(".cancel").click(function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).closest('tr').find("#backsheet").show();
                   });
                   $(".buttonClose").click(function() {
                       $(this).closest('#backsheet').hide();
                   });
                   $(".buttonCancel").click(function() {
                        $(this).closest('#backsheet').hide();
                   });

                 });
    </script>
```

You need to learn that if you have a loop you need classes to the elements in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Issue looks only at the place at
`onclick="return validation();"`

What is there at validation part?

Also the structure you are creating is incorrect. It will create table structure like,

```
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<div></div>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<div></div>
</table>
```

Sometime IE may create issue for invalid tag structure.